# Using multiple VLOOKUPs with IF statements

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

I have three sets of data. I must pull information from three reports to collate their data on the original report. The function would read like this if written out in English:

run VLOOKUP on database1, if value does not equal #N/A do nothing, if value equals #N/A then
run VLOOKUP on database2, if value does not equal #N/A do nothing, if value equals #N/A then
run VLOOKUP on database3

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something like:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(?,1?:?,1?),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(?,2?:?,2?),VLOOKUP(?,3?:?,3?)))
```

(or a rather longer version with `IF(ISERROR(...`s if you software is old).

This though would not be specific to the `#N/A` error. For example, other errors if encountered when searching `1?:?` will lead to an attempt to search `2?:?`.